# Metaprop Forest Plot Heading Change

Tags: r

I'm doing a meta-analysis of proportions using metaprop in R. I'm trying to make my final forest plots look better, but have been having issues removing the heading "Common effect model" or even renaming it to the conventional "Fixed effects model". I've looked through the code for labels that may be correct and also across google, but can't find anyone with a similar issue. Any help would be appreciated.

```
pes.summary=metaprop(cases,total,authoryear,data=dat,sm="PLO",method.ci="NAsm",method.tau="DL",incr=0.5,allincr=FALSE,addincr=FALSE,title="")
png("forestplotMassDXA.png",width=800,height=1200)
forest(pes.summary,
       xlim = c(0,1), pscale =1, 
       rightcols=c("effect", "ci","w.random"),
       rightlabs=c("Proportion", "95% C.I.","Weights"),
       leftcols = c("studlab", "event", "n"), 
       leftlabs = c("Study", "Successful", "Total"),
       xlab = "Proportion", 
       fs.xlab=12,
       fs.study=12,
       fs.study.lables=12,
       fs.heading=12,
       squaresize = 0.5, col.square="navy", col.square.lines="navy",
       col.diamond="navy", col.diamond.lines="navy",
       comb.fixed=FALSE,
       lty.fixed=0,
       lty.random=2, 
       Modality.study="square",
       type.random="diamond",
       ff.fixed="bold.italic",
       ff.random="bold.italic",
       hetlab = "Heterogeneity:",
       fs.hetstat=8,
       smlab="",
       print.Q=TRUE,
       print.pval.Q=TRUE,
       print.I2=TRUE,
       print.tau2=FALSE,
       col.by="black")
```

[How my forest plot looks]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/arkDK.png

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you. I will amend the above now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need this, but to remove it you could just add `common = FALSE` in your command so it looks like this:

```
forest(pes.summary,
       xlim = c(0,1), pscale =1, 
       rightcols=c("effect", "ci","w.random"),
       rightlabs=c("Proportion", "95% C.I.","Weights"),
       leftcols = c("studlab", "event", "n"), 
       leftlabs = c("Study", "Successful", "Total"),
       xlab = "Proportion", 
       fs.xlab=12,
       fs.study=12,
       fs.study.lables=12,
       fs.heading=12,
       squaresize = 0.5, col.square="navy", col.square.lines="navy",
       col.diamond="navy", col.diamond.lines="navy",
       comb.fixed=FALSE,
       lty.fixed=0,
       lty.random=2, 
       Modality.study="square",
       type.random="diamond",
       ff.fixed="bold.italic",
       ff.random="bold.italic",
       hetlab = "Heterogeneity:",
       fs.hetstat=8,
       smlab="",
       print.Q=TRUE,
       print.pval.Q=TRUE,
       print.I2=TRUE,
       print.tau2=FALSE,
       col.by="black",
       common = FALSE)
```

But to change it to the conventional `Fixed-effect model` is another story. I am eager to know if someone manages to do it

Comment: I also would love to know if you can change it to say "fixed effect" instead of "common effect"! Can't find anything online about this...