# Change R Metaprop Forest Plot to print "Fixed Effects" instead of "Common Effects"?

Tags: r, statistics, r-forestplot

I'm doing a meta-analysis in R using metaprop from the meta package. Pretty straightforward using the following lines of code, where `data` is my input dataframe with columns for 'Events', 'Subjects' and 'Author'.

```
pes.summary  <- metaprop(`Events`, `Subjects`, `Author` , data = data , sm = "PFT")
forest(pes.summary)
```

Is there a way to change the outputted forest plot to print "Fixed effects model" instead of "Common effects model"? Ideally looking for a way to do this natively through R Meta. Not much documentation about this situation online, which leads me to believe the answer is no. I did find one other thread on StackOverflow about it here:

[Metaprop Forest Plot Heading Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72954283/metaprop-forest-plot-heading-change)

See picture below for reference:

[image: Forest plot example]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

```
forest(pes.summary, text.common = 'Fixed')
```